# Like button is not working

Tags: php, ajax, facebook-like

I am using AJAX and in the page I have used this script.
It's working on local server. But it's not working on the live server.

```
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var fb = document.createElement('fb:like');
        fb.setAttribute("href","<?php echo 'http://bagstudio.co.uk/menu_details.php?pid='.$product_id; ?>")
        fb.setAttribute("layout","button_count");
        fb.setAttribute("show_faces","false");
        fb.setAttribute("width","100");
        fb.setAttribute("font","arial");
        document.getElementById("FaceBookLikeButton").appendChild(fb);
        //]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: means like button is not displaying on live site but working and displaying on local server

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your error console. You could have an error somewhere else on the page. That could cause the whole thing to crash. I suggest that because your code worked perfectly fine for me. Also verify that there is in fact an element with the id `FaceBookLikeButton`